# what version of UI bootstrap works with Angular 1.6.4?

Tags: angularjs

I am using AngularJS v1.6.4 and bootstrap version is v3.3.4 and ui-bootstrap v2.5.0. I'm trying to use dropdown button but its not working but when using  AngularJS v1.5.11 and bootstrap version is v3.3.4.Button dropdown is working.

```
<ul class="heroes" ng-repeat="role in names">
  <li ng-if="role.accessMethod == 1">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
      <span class="badge">{{role.code}}</span> 
    </button>
  </li>
  <li ng-if="role.accessMethod == 2">
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
        <span class="badge">{{role.code}}</span> <span class="caret"></span><span class="sr-only"></span>
      </button>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
        <li ng-repeat="roledetail in role.roles" ng-click="onSelect(roledetail.roleName)">
          <a href="">{{roledetail.roleName}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and the json for it is

```
$scope.names = [{
  "code": "abc",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "1",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "B"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "code": "XYZ",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "2",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "B"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "code": "Neo",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "2",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "C"
    }
  ]
}, {
  "code": "LAB",
  "name": null,
  "accessMethod": "1",
  "roles": [{
      "roleId": 1,
      "roleName": "A"
    },
    {
      "roleId": 3,
      "roleName": "B"
    }
  ]
}];
```

In the above code i'm trying to use different buttons based on access Method   one is simple button when access method is 1 and another is button dropdown when access method is 2.When i'm using angular version 1.6.4 with bootstrap version 3.3.4 and uI-bootstrap version 2.5.0 i'm unable to get button dropdown